# Is every fusion category with unitary $S$ a unitary modular tensor category (UMTC)?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer, topological-field-theory, anyons, category-theory

A tensor category whose solutions to the pentagon/hexagon equations are unitary and whose braiding is nondegenerate is called a *unitary modular tensor category* (UMTC). When trying to find UMTCs, modularity demands that the relevant $S$-matrix is *necessarily* unitary (this guarantees nondegenerate braiding). Imposing this condition on $S$ helps to discard models which describe unphysical theories (a technique that is used e.g. by *Wang et al.* in https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.1377). From this, it is clear (and obvious through terminology) that:

$\{UMTCs\} \subseteq \{\text{fusion categories with unitary } $S$\}$

*Note:* From discussion in the comments below, it appears that fusion categories with unitary $S$ are called MTCs. I will word my question on this basis.

What I don't know is whether or not demanding $S$ unitary is necessary and sufficient for yielding a UMTC i.e. *is it true that*

$\{UMTCs\} = \{MTCs\}$  ?

Are there no counterexamples i.e. does demanding $S$ unitary always mean there exists a solution with $F$ and $R$ symbols unitary?

**EDIT:** Refer to https://mathoverflow.net/q/284647/  for the refined version of this question.

Comment: The wording of your question is a little bit confusing. By "anyonic tensor category", do you actually mean a UMTC which can be realized as the topological excitations of some Hamiltonian? The way your question is worded seems like it's asking a mathematical question about whether all unitary tensor categories are necessarily modular -- which is certainly not true.

Comment: Actually, I guess your question reads as asking whether every UMTC is a unitary tensor category -- which is vacuously true...

Comment: Essentially: does $S$ unitary always imply that its associated fusion rules have unitary solutions for $F$ and $R$ symbols? Or are there cases where this isn't true?

Comment: OK, so I guess you're asking whether every braided fusion category with unitary S matrix is unitary. I don't know the answer to that, but you had better edit your question, because the definition of UMTC by definition includes unitarity of F and R so the way you worded it is not correct. It's also really a math question, not a physics one, so might be worth asking on mathoverflow or math.stackexchange.

Comment: One more question on terminology: In the term UMTC, does 'unitary' refer to unitarity of F and R, and modularity refer to the unitarity of S (which is necessarily true for unitarity of F and R)? I.e. UTC vs UMTC vs MTC

Comment: Yes, "unitary" means unitarity of F and R, "modular" means unitarity of S and T.

Comment: It really seems like you might get some mileage out of my dissertation. I'm not advocating that it is impeccably written, but it was constructed, in part, to answer and clarify the kinds of questions you're asking, specifically for physicists.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, where might I find it?

Comment: Send me an email. It's the same as in the papers, though switch out "utdallas.edu" for "unt.edu."

Answer (score 3):

Unitarity of the $S$ matrix in a modular tensor category does not imply that it is a unitary modular tensor category. In fact, the $S$ matrix is symmetric and unitary even in a ribbon fusion category (see Theorem 4.23 [here](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Ezhenghwa/data/course/cbms.pdf)). However, unitarity of the modular tensor category is a stronger constraint.

For example, both the Fibonacci and Yang-Lee anyon models have unitary S matrices (you can find the explicit expressions in the reference cited above). The former is unitary, while the latter is non-unitary.

A MTC is unitary if the quantum dimensions are positive and if there exists a gauge in which $F$ symbols are unitary (if $F$ is unitary $R$ is automatically unitary (see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.2022v2))).